# vertical aling in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

helllo evryone.

i have 4 divs that i want to be in one line in bootstrap but i have some problems with alignement, this picture shows the result:
[It is looking like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruX3Q.png)

the image is not in one line as other element and the text x cm is not in the center of its div

this my code

```css
.flt{
    float: left
}
.info-ingr{
    background-color: #5bc0de;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    color: white;
}

.alginement{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #faa;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
    <div id="painchamp0" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/long-loaf-bread-22826883.jpg" class="img-responsive"><!--"img/pain-sandwich"-->
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <select class="ste form-control" id="painList0">
                        <option>Select type de pain :</option>
                        <option>Pain complet</option>
                        <option>Pain aux céréales</option>
                        <option>Pain au seigle</option>
                        <option>Pain au levain</option>
                        <option>Pain aux épices</option>
                        <option>Pain aux figues</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1" >
                    <input type="number" step="8" value="0" min="0" max="64" placeholder="largeur de pain :" id="painQuantite0"  class="form-control flt"> 
                
                </div >
                 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 align-lg-middle alginement" >
                     x cm
                 </div>   
                <div  class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    
                    <button id="painBTN0" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md flt">
                    ok
                    </button>

                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

thank you

Comment: You need to include Bootstrap, and mark up your form controls as per Bootstrap conventions.... for a start :)

Comment: is this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BWzdjP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, text content having **padding(10px) property**..Just scrolldown to find  that corresponding property line while you inspect it in the browser

Comment: thank you for your response but i don't still understand why the object is not exactly in one line with others
thank you

Comment: hey your `col-xs` separation exceeds 12 section..you have used `col-xs-10,col-xs-3,col-xs-1,col-xs-1` totally it means `col-xs-15`..this is 150%..first go through the grid section of bootstrap here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: ooh ya
i didn't see it,
thank you @Jana
i will try with that